# C# MVC dont let user key in index in the url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, url, routes

Allow the user to key the URL 
`http://example.com/controller`  to get the action "index"

How do I disable the 
`http://example.com/controller/index`
so that the link will redirect to `http://example.com/controller`

Comment: What do you mean _disable_ it? The user can enter whatever they want into the address bar.

Comment: so that the link will redirect to http://example.com/controller instead of the url is http://example.com/controller/index

Comment: Both `../controller/index` and `../controller` will go to to the `Index()` method of the named controller assuming your using the default routes. You cannot stop a user entering `../controller/index` in the address bar if they want to.

Comment: I looking any chances to redirect the ../controller/index to ../controller by configuring something on the route.map() or any others method.

Comment: You will need to use configure URL rewrite in IIS

Comment: Are you using .net core?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe don't have configuration on the route , I have to do with the method below.

```
public ActionResult Index(){
      string item = Url.Content(Request.Url.PathAndQuery);


      if (item.Equals("/controller/index", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
      {
         return Redirect("/controller");
      }else
      {
           return View();
      }
}
```